# Angular Ui Router + Animate.css

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate, animate.css

view`animation on state change with`animate.css`
But when writing this:

```
<div ui-view class="view-animation"></div>

//(sass)

.view-animation{
    &.ng-enter {
        -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 2s;
        -moz-animation: fadeInLeft 2s;
        -ms-animation: fadeInLeft 2s;
        animation: fadeInLeft 2s;
    }

    &.ng-leave {
        -webkit-animation: bounceOut 1s;
        -moz-animation: bounceOut 1s;
        -ms-animation: bounceOut 1s;
        animation: bounceOut 1s;
    }
}
```

There is 2 sec delay, and in the end content just appears(Similar if I do timeout and apply display:block via js), but animation is not visible.

But when writing this:

```
.view-animation.ng-enter,
.view-animation.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease all;
  transition:0.5s ease all;
}

.view-animation.ng-enter,
.view-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
.view-animation.ng-leave,
.view-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

All works fine

I've tried adding `position:absolute; width: 100%;` to `.view-animation` but didn't helped.

Thank you.

**Update:**

Applying `fadeIn` animation also works fine, maybe it have something to do with animations that use transform?

**Update 2:**

Ok inside my `ui-view.view-animation` I have an element with position `fixed` this cause animation break, is there is any workaround for this?

**Update 3:**
adding this to `.view-animation`

```
.view-animation{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
}
```

Solved my issue, if you have better solution please share.